# jQuery id change in url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am working on a page where I have to change the url dynamically.

Currently URL is something like this:

```
http://localhost/AdurCup/product.php?id=DJEBMDCVEKPCJAAA
```

I have to change the id part on the basis of drop down.

[image]

When I select the different option in drop down, then id part in url also changes. like in the url `id=DJEBMDCVEKPCJAAA changes to id=DJEBHDCVCSBDAAAA`

Here, only id part is changing.

Comment: `location.search = "?id=" + newId;`

Comment: try using window.history.pushState